# How to get all the child elements or children in a collection view (xamarin forms)

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, collectionview

I want to access the child controls or children elements in the collection view. when my page appears , I create the Data template object with the controls required depending upon the Json object.

On clicking the submit button i pass the collection view as a parameter to the model view but cant find controls or children elements been created.

```
<CollectionView x:Name="ExampleCollectionView" ItemsSource="{Binding AllQuestionSurvey}">
   <CollectionView.FooterTemplate>    
     <DataTemplate>
         <StackLayout Padding="10">
            <Button Text="Submit"Command="{Binding SubmitButtonCommand }" CommandParameter="{Binding Source={x:Reference ExampleCollectionView}}"/>
         </StackLayout>
     </DataTemplate>
   </CollectionView.FooterTemplate>
   <CollectionView.ItemTemplate >                             
     **<Classes:QuestionTemplateSelector> </Classes:QuestionTemplateSelector>**
   </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

[i want to access  the controls i have created to get the responses for each question.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4N2k.png)

Comment: this is what data binding is for.  You bind your UI to a ViewModel, then get the user's input from the ViewModel.  You do not directly access the UI elements in the CollectionView.

Comment: do you mean binding each control created to a property ?. could you please elaborate a bit as i am new to xamarin.thanks

Comment: you presumably have a List of Question objects that you are binding to your LIstView - each row will map to a Question.  Each Question should also have a Response property where you capture whatever the user's input was.  Then you get the list of the User's responses by checking the Response property of each Question

Comment: let me try this out ... thank you.